# Marklogic - Adding a default rule set through admin console

Tags: sparql, marklogic, rules, inference

I have defined a default ruleset through admin console. I have given the location of the ruleset as "C:/isParentOf.rules". However, it is not able to find this file. While running a query, it is complaining that 
" The ruleset file cannot be found: C:/isParentOf.rules"

I have tried giving a relative path but it does not seem to work.
Can someone suggest what is the right way to specify the location of the ruleset and where ideally should it be kept (along with existing .rules files)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Custom rulesets can be placed inside the MarkLogic installation dir under Config/, but I'd recommend uploading it to the schemas database. See also:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/inferencing#id_pgfId-924845

HTH!